# Ruby/Rails worker to create or update record if exists - avoid DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got worker to store data from incoming webhooks. Now I want to use this worker to update existing data if this data already exists.

```
class StoreActivityWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(webhook)
    Activity.create!(
      cms_activity_id: webhook.dig('entity', 'id').to_i,
      is_separate_activity: webhook.dig('entity', 'attributes', 'is_separate_activity'),
      content_full: retrieve_full_content(webhook),
      content_basic: retrieve_basic_content(webhook),
    )
  end
end
```

Because the webhook does not show which records have been updated the `UpdateActivityWorker` will be the same (update all fields):

```
class UpdateActivityWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(webhook)
    Activity.where(cms_activity_id: webhook[:entity][:id]).update(
      cms_activity_id: webhook.dig('entity', 'id').to_i,
      is_separate_activity: webhook.dig('entity', 'attributes', 'is_separate_activity'),
      content_full: retrieve_full_content(webhook),
      content_basic: retrieve_basic_content(webhook),
    )
  end
end
```

As you see it's not inline with DRY. Is there any way to avoid repeats that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [find_or_initialize_by](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by) method:

```
class StoreActivityWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(webhook)
    entity = webhook.dig 'entity'

    activity = Activity.find_or_initialize_by(cms_activity_id: entity['id'])

    activity.update!(
      is_separate_activity: entity.dig('attributes', 'is_separate_activity'),
      content_full: retrieve_full_content(webhook),
      content_basic: retrieve_basic_content(webhook),
    )
  end
end
```